# Research field of timeseries with unpaired measurements?

Tags: time-series, unevenly-spaced-time-series, nonlinear-dynamical-system

I have measurements of cells' gene expression at different time points (t0, t1, t2, ...). Cells die when measured and therefore all measurements are from different samples, i.e. I do not observe any sample at two different timepoints. However all cells start from a very similar (not exact) starting point (cell culture). The equilibrium of all cells belongs to one of two possible cell types. Hence, there are two trajectories (which are overlapping in the beginning).

I'd like to learn the (nonlinear) dynamics of these cells (I guess it does not matter what objects I study). I also assume that a cell's expression follows an SDE:
$dx = f(x,t)dt+g(x,t)dw$, where $x$ is gene expression, $t$ is time and $w$ denotes a Wiener process. If necessary I could assume that $f$ is linear, e.g., $dx = (A(t) \cdot x(t)) dt + g(x,t)dw$

What is the research field/keywords I need to look into to find existing models when I have these "unpaired" measurement points?

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to say more about your differential equation, in particular what $w$ is (I assume that $x$ is the gene expression). Also, say more about the nature of the experimental setup and data collection. Although the particular cells sampled might die, they presumably are representative of some higher-level construct (e.g., one of multiple culture dishes from the same cell strain in the same experiment), so that you have repeated measures at that higher level. Editing the question is preferable to adding a comment, as comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.

Comment: Thanks, I added more comments to clarify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The recent review by Craigmile et al., [Statistical inference for stochastic differential equations](https://doi.org/10.1002/wics.1585), WIREs Comput Stat. 2023; 15: e1585, is a good introduction to fitting data to systems that combine drift (your $f(x,t)dt$ term) with diffusion (your $g(x,t)dw$ term). The problem you note is that in your situation you aren't sampling the same system repeatedly over time, but rather sampling different instances of the same underlying system (cells, in your example) only once each, at different times.

Although this is far beyond my expertise in statistics, I suspect that it should be possible in principle to devise a formula for the likelihood of finding your one-time-sampled per-cell data as a function of the parameters of your model. The basic idea is that the spread in expression values (due to diffusion) among instances of a single cell type (with cell types presumably distinguished by drift parameters) will increase over time in a way that is given by the solution to the SDE.

As a biologist, however, I'm somewhat skeptical that this will end up being a useful way to understand what's going on in the cells. It might succeed in describing the observed expression values adequately, but it won't elucidate the network of intracellular processes, involving large numbers of products of other genes, that regulate expression of this particular gene. You might get just as good a description of your data by fitting a model (parametric or a flexible fit like a regression spline) to the data over time and reporting on how much the dispersion increases over time.